# Product of manifolds with boundary

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

If $M$ and $N$ are manifolds with boundaries and $\{(U_a,f_a)\}$ and $\{(V_a,g_a)\}$ are their respectives $C^r$ atlas,  why $\{(U_a \times V_b,f_a \times g_b)\}$ isn't an $C^r$ atlas for $M \times N$?

I tried to compose the maps and show that they are not $C ^ r$, but got no contradiction. It's probably simple, but I don't get it.

Comment: The problem is that the product is a manifold with corners and at the corners the image of the product of local coordinate maps is not a half-space intersected with an open set.

Comment: Consider $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and the points $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)\,\&\, (1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

When $a\in \partial M$ and $b\in\partial N$, the map $f_a\times g_b$ sends a $C^r$-diffeomorphism of $U_a\times V_b$ onto a neighborhood of a corner in the product of two closed halfspaces. This is not  what the charts on a manifold with boundary are supposed to do. They should map neighborhoods onto open subsets of $[0,\infty)\times \mathbb R^{d-1}$.